# Detecting screen content changes and simulating touch commands accordingly

Tags: screen, automation, touch

Say there is an app that shows a red color rectangle. If the app is kept open, the color of the rectangle changes to yellow after some time. When this happens, I want to detect that a color change happened, and simulate a touch on the rectangle.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related on SoftwareRecs.SE: [Android app for detecting screen content changes and simulating touch commands](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/86939/520)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Automate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en_US&gl=US). ([docs](https://llamalab.com/automate/))

[image: 3]

To detect changes and interact with the UI:

[image: 4] [image]

It's pretty self explanatory. You can record interactions and save it right away. Also it's one of the most optimised and light weight automation app I've seen so far.